# How to set iframe Src from Javascript Var

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've reviewed many similar posts but couldn't figure it out (probably bc my knowledge in js is non-existent).

I've created a page, you can review it here:
https://hodiva.com/pages/test-tracking?tracking=0100668631422

As you can see in the Alert window, the script produces the desired URL,
but I can't find how to set that as the `<iframe> src`

-- The desired iframe src url is what I get from "var combined".

Here's the full code of my page:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var mainParameter = window.location.search;
var address = "https://dealtas.com/tracking"
var combined = address + mainParameter;
var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame").src;

  alert(combined);
});
</script>
<body>
<iframe id="MyFrame" style="width:100%;height:800px;overflow:scroll;"></iframe>
</body>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById("MyFrame").src = newValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the attribute of the `<iframe>` with javascript by using `element.setAttribute()`
**What you gonna add is:** `document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", combined);`
Also don't forget to put the script after loading the `<iframe>`.
Here is your full code:

```
<body>
   <iframe id="MyFrame" style="width:100%;height:800px;overflow:scroll;"></iframe>
   <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
         var mainParameter = window.location.search;
         var address = "https://dealtas.com/tracking"
         var combined = address + mainParameter;
         var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame").src;

         document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", combined); //Change the src's value!
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

Snippet:

```html
    <body>
       <iframe id="MyFrame" style="width:100%;height:800px;overflow:scroll;"></iframe>
       <script>
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
             var mainParameter = window.location.search;
             var address = "https://dealtas.com/tracking"
             var combined = address + mainParameter;
             var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame").src;
    
             document.getElementById('MyFrame').setAttribute("src", combined); //Change the src's value!
          });
       </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it like this ...

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
var mainParameter = window.location.search;
var address = "https://dealtas.com/tracking"
var combined = address + mainParameter;
var iframeSrcValue = document.getElementById("MyFrame");

iframeSrcValue.src = combined;

  //alert(combined);
});
</script>
<body>
<iframe id="MyFrame" style="width:100%;height:800px;overflow:scroll;"></iframe>
</body>
```